# Array in JSON file isn't being identified as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I've got an error which is driving me to insanity.. Basically all I'm trying to do is repeat a `li` for each item in an array. Instead I get this:

[`ng-repeat error`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SM3r.png)

When I retrieve the JSON it appears that the array isn't being noticed. Instead it just puts everything together to create a long comma separated string. Why is this?

When I retrieve the JSON file I bind it to the scope like this:

```
$http.get('jsons/' + $routeParams.pieId + '.json')
     .success(function(data) {
        $scope.pie = data;
     });
```

Is there anything wrong here? Why isn't the JSON noticing my array?

This is the JSON that I fetch:

```
{
    "name": "Raspberry pie", 
    "imageUrl": "img/raspberrypie.jpg",
    "rating": 5,
    "description": "Sweet and fresh raspberries are topped with a quick raspberry sauce in this tempting summer dessert. Serve chilled with a dollop of whipped cream.",
    "ingredients": ["Water", "raspberries", "cornstarch", "sugar", "lemon", "wheat", "egg", "milk", "butter"],
    "price": 4.89
}
```

But this is what comes out:

```
{
    "name": "Raspberry pie", 
    "imageUrl": "img/raspberrypie.jpg",
    "rating": 5,
    "description": "Sweet and fresh raspberries are topped with a quick raspberry sauce in this tempting summer dessert. Serve chilled with a dollop of whipped cream.",
    "ingredients": "Water, raspberries, cornstarch, sugar, lemon, wheat, egg, milk, butter",
    "price": 4.89
}
```

Notice the difference at `ingredients`.

Comment: I put your code in exactly as-is into a plnkr and it seems to work correctly with and without the track-by  http://plnkr.co/edit/s8xbGPfIIK8pZhAzz74Q?p=preview What exact version of angular are you on, maybe there's  bug?

Comment: @NicholasSmith I'm on 1.3.10. I've never come across this bug before.. It's a really strange one.

Comment: Since we can't replicate the issue with what you provided, then you will need to provide more information to show the issue. Preferably your own small example in a plunkr.

Comment: @MatthewGreen I'm on it

Comment: I did the same thing with 1.3.10 and also not getting the error. http://plnkr.co/edit/xJReGjy5ESacr4qKW0lS?p=preview  Can you reproduce it on plnkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: do you have an interceptor or do you modify t jason in any way? it seems yo me you are doing repeat orver a comma joined version of the array

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I just console logged to see the $scope.pie object and the ingredients property is in fact not an array at all for some reason..

Comment: @NicholasSmith Updated question with the problem.

Comment: can you include the full response with headers for a request of your JSON document?

Comment: you may have an interceptor that is skipping the JSON parsing, going deeper requires viewing more of your code. can you paste what your log looks like?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon My console.log?

Comment: yes, you said it was not json, what does it look like then?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon ingredients: "Water, apples, sugar, wheat, egg, milk, butter, nutmeg, shortening" is what it gives me. Instead of an array with each ingredient being it's own index

Comment: lol yup ok then just do string.spli(',') on your assignment and you should be ok,  also close this question and open a new one if you want to find out what the root problem is, don't get down voted ;)

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon Why would I need to open a new question for that? My question here is what's causing it, opening a new one wouldn't really add anything.

Comment: oh sorry i thought the question title was about ng-repeat failing :0 nm